# Not able to run react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack.config.js

I am new to reactjs. i am trying to write webpack.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: './main.js',
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
  filename: 'index_bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 3000
},
module: {
  rules: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
     },
     {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
            }
        }]
     }
  ]
  },
  plugins:[
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: './index.html'
  })
 ]
 }
```

Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\react-app\index.html' in 'F:\  react-app':
  Error: Can't resolve 'F:\react-app\index.html' in 'F:\react-app'

- compiler.js:141 
  [react-app]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:141:18
- Compiler.js:306 
  [react-app]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:306:11
- Compiler.js:631 
  [react-app]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:631:15
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [react-app]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compiler.js:628 
  [react-app]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:628:31
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [react-app]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1325 
  [react-app]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1325:35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plugins:[
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     hash:'true'
     template: './index.html'
  })
 ]
```

Put hash to true and make sure you have the correct location of the template file.